# DataGridView won't populate text

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am Using WinForms, framework 4.6.1.

I have two DataGridView controls, on a TabControl, each on its own TabPage.

I have two small classes which I use as the DataSources for each individual DataGridView. In both instances I create a `List< myClasses >`, where myClasses are one of

```
internal sealed class cls_grid
{
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }

        internal cls_grid(string _id, string _value)
        {
            id = _id;
            value = _value;
        }
 }
```

OR

```
internal sealed class cls_image
{
        public List<cls_image_data_grid> 
               cls_image_data = new List<cls_image.cls_image_data_grid>();

        public string tab_text;
        public Bitmap image;

        internal class cls_image_data_grid
        {
            public string id;
            public string value;

            internal cls_image_data_grid(string _id, string _value)
            {
                id = _id;
                value = _value;
            }
        }

        internal cls_image(string _tab_text, Bitmap _image)
        {
            tab_text = _tab_text;
            image = _image;
        }
 }
```

There is absolutely NO difference in my two DataGridViews; I can say that with absolute certainty because I have my own DataGridView class which inherits the framework DataGridView class, so all properties that I set take effect on both, except for the name of course.

However, my first DataGridView using class **cls_grid** populates perfectly, but my DataGridView using class **cls_image.cls_image_data_grid** won’t populate. The DataGridView creates the amount of rows that are present in the List at the time, but there is no text in the DataGridView. Not even when I make all my properties or my internal class public, does it work.

If I copy the values from **List< cls_image.cls_image_data_grid >** into **List< cls_grid >**, and pass that to the DataGridView instead, it populates perfectly well.

So now my question is, are there any limitations on the DataGridView DataSource and what it will or will not accept, or what could the issue be?

Comment: Take a look at [Naming Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines)

Comment: @RezaAghaei I agree that the naming conventions aren't quite as they should be in this case, but there is a good reason behind it. I don't think the grid doesn't populate because of naming conventions?

Comment: DataSource loves properties.

Comment: @TaW I am such a nana! And you are absolutely spot on. I don't know how I missed that... sometimes you just need four eyes. Added the get set and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @Bazïnga They are just awkward, not harmful.